How to Add a Component to a Repeatable Field in Strapi 5 Using Document Service?
I'm currently working with Strapi v5 and trying to add a component to a content type that includes a repeatable component field. I want to use the Document Service for this task, but I can't find the appropriate documentation or examples to guide me.
Context:

I have a content type (e.g., Article) that has a repeatable component field (e.g., seo).
I'm unsure how to properly update this field to add new components programmatically using the Document Service.

Questions:

Is it possible to add a component to a repeatable field using the Document Service in Strapi 5?
If so, could someone provide a code example or point me to the relevant documentation?
Alternatively, if the Document Service doesn’t support this, would using raw queries with strapi.db.connection be a suitable approach?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!
